# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (540,2500) (540,)

Tags: python, image, numpy, array-broadcasting

i am trying to divide each x-value by its row mean

```
train_rows_mean = train_data.mean(axis=1) #calculate the mean row_wise

#divide each value by row mean
train_data/train_rows_mean #broadcasting issue

print(train_data.shape) #shape of train data
print(train_rows_mean.shape) #shape of mean
```

but i get this error

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (540,2500) (540,)
```

Comment: Use keepdims: `train_data.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `train_data` is a 2-dimensional array, try:

```
train_data/train_rows_mean[:, None]
```

This adds a new dimension to `train_rows_mean` before dividing

Answer (score 0):

As @Mechanic Pig mentioned in his comment, you need to to preserve the dimension so that numpy can broadcast along it. For more information, look at the docs [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules).

Also, if you need to take mean row-wise, you need to use axis=0

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
a_mean = a.mean(axis=0, keepdims=True) #has dimensions 1x2
out = a/a_mean
```